# Thymeleaf site doesn't read content of css file

Tags: html, css, spring, tomcat, thymeleaf

I try to write my website with spring framework in back- and thymeleaf in frontend on tomcat local server. I try add css to my html file. Css file seems to be linked on server, but devtools shows that it is empty. Do you know what could i miss?

**EDIST**: sorry for posting pictures, I will know better next time. I left minimum i wanted to show.

index.css

```css
h1{
color: red;
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleag.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" th:href="@{../css/index.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <a href="greeting">Greeting</a>
    <a href="registration">Registration</a>
</body>
</html>
```

HomePageController.java

```java
package com.krs.GreatBookOfDiet.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class HomePageController {

    @GetMapping("")
    public String index(Map<String, Object> model){
        return "index";
    }

}
```

GreatBookOfDietConfiguration.java

```java
package com.krs.GreatBookOfDiet;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebProperties;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

import java.util.Locale;

@Configuration
public class GreatBookOfDietConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/pdf/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver thymeleafResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setOrder(0);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

}
```

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEmMN.png)

[devtools on server, index.css view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoEdr.png)

Comment: first of all try to put correct link to thymeleaf: xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, I don't use stack a lot :/. I tried with the link in html document. Nothing happened. Still, I get a file on the server, but it is empty. :c
If you need something more I can share project.

Comment: You need to add to your question your Spring MVC configuration (`@Configuration` class or XML file). By default Spring's `DispatcherServlet` does not serve any static resource (cf. [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-config-static-resources)) and Tomcat's default servlet does not serve the contents of `/WEB-INF`.

Answer (score 0):

Your static resources in the `/WEB-INF/css` folder are not served by Spring, therefore a request for `http://example.com/app/css/index.css` returns a 404 error.

You need to modify your `addResourceHandlers` method:

```java
   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**")
              .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/pdf/");
      registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
              .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/css/");
   }
```

**Remark**: Given the popularity of Spring Boot, you might consider using the same locations for static resources (cf. [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-web-applications.spring-mvc.static-content)), which sums up to the following configuration:

```java
   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
              .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/");
   }
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried to adjust my ResourceHandler to what you said and it doesn't work still (404 error while trying to reach file). I believe it may be one of the reasons, but still don't work. I don't understand the second part of the answer about the same locations, you mean should I put everything like .pdf and .css files in one directory?